# JS script to convert latex formula into a single image

Tags: javascript, image, latex

Is there an online JS script/library to convert any latex expression like `$\frac{a}{b}+\frac{c}{d}$` into a single image on a webpage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it by way of the [Google Chart API](https://ardoris.wordpress.com/2010/06/27/converting-inline-latex-to-images-with-javascript-and-google-chart-api/). That's probably the simplest way.

There is also a Javascript port of [`pdflatex`](http://manuels.github.io/texlive.js/) but that prints PDFs only. You can make images out of it with [PDF.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js) by [rendering it into a `canvas` object](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/examples/helloworld/hello.js).

If you just need a way to display formulas you might give [MathJS](http://www.math.union.edu/~dpvc/jsMath/) a try (it is also used here at the mathematically inclined goups) which has a fallback using images although images of the individual characters only not the whole equation.

Comment: that google chart api is so simple, tks

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:
http://blog.dreasgrech.com/2009/12/jslatex-jquery-plugin-to-directly-embed.html

Here you need to write the latex in html. In my project I had used this.

Demo: http://dreasgrech.com/upload/jslatex/demos.html

Answer (score 0):

Use [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/), a JavaScript display engine for mathematics.  It is free, open source, in current development, state of the art, supported by the American Mathematical Society among others.